# How to use Rules to perform a monthtly reset of a field for all users accounts?

Tags: 7, users, rules

Once a month I would like to reset a field on all users accounts to 0.

At the moment I have a horrible way of doing it. Each time a user logs in the data is scheduled to be changed only for that user. This is done through a rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) which whenever a user logs in runs 'Schedule component evaluation' with a data selector of `site:current-user` and a date of the first of the month. The component that the rule calls 'set a data value' of 0. This is obviously not an efficient way of handling this. However it does work.

Ideally I would like to have a rule that runs occasionally, I could use when cron is run. This rule would schedule setting the data value for all users of the site. The problem is that I don't seem to have a data selector of 'all users' to pass to the component.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Hi Gisle. No it doesn't have to be rules based, but simple is always good with me ;) I have made a few small custom modules, but haven't set data with them so far. Could you give a few more ideas as to how to set data values within a `hook_cron` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small module for this to write some code using [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7).

Inside hook function you can write query to collect all the user ID & update one field value in loop.

Then use [Elsia Cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to schedule your made cron function.

Comment: Sounds good. Looks like I should be able to use cron debug to help test things https://drupal.org/project/cron_debug

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have "***... a data selector of 'all users' ...***" in your rule (as in your question), then a possible solution is to make one available in an appropriately triggered Rules Event, as further detailed below.

#### Step 1: Trigger a monthly rule

Create a rule using the [Rules Once per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday) module to actually trigger a rule once a ***month*** (not ***day***!). And add a Rules Condition "***Day of the month***" (which comes with this module also). Further configure this Rules Condition with an actual "*Day of month** (an integer between 1 and 31) to actually fit your needs. E.g.: if you specify `1` as your *Day of month*, this rule will be triggered on the 1st of every month.

As an example, have a look at this simplistic rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_monthly_email_reminder_to_admin_account" : {
    "LABEL" : "Monthly eMail reminder to admin account",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules_onceperday", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "once_per_day" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "rules_onceperday_condition_dayofmonth" : { "comparison" : "==", "monthday" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "site:mail" ],
          "subject" : "Time for the monthly operations on the 1st of every month",
          "message" : "It\u0027s the 1st day of the month again, time for the monthly operations ...",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All this rule does, is to send an eMail to the site admin, on the 1st of every month, with a subject like "*Time for the monthly operations on the 1st of every month*" (and some eMail body that goes with it).

If you have the Rules UI enabled, and after you also enabled the [Rules Ones per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday) module, you should be able to just import the above rule in your own site.

#### Step 2: Create a view of all users to be processed

Create a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) of those users for which you want to "*reset a field to 0*" (as in your question).

#### Step 3: Make the monthly rule process all users

After you created such view, you can ***process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)***, by replacing the Rules Action in the rule from Step 1 like so:

- Load the VBO list of the users in your View.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action to "*reset a field to 0*" (as in your question), for each user contained in your Views result.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".